ESLint found too many warnings (maximum: -1)
I do not see any errors or actual warnings but my nx affected:lint is failing with:

ESLint found too many warnings (maximum: -1)

This happened when trying to upgrade NX from version 17 to version 19

Solution: set an actual max warnings limit in the nx.json file:
"maxWarnings": 0

In the targetDefaults.lint.options object.
Example:
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/nx/schemas/nx-schema.json",
  // ...
  "targetDefaults": {
    // ...
    "lint": {
      "inputs": [ /* ... */ ],
      "options": {
        "maxWarnings": 0
      }
    },
  },
}

